# OpenGL - Does MSAA not support floating-point texture?

Tags: opengl-4, deferred-rendering

Here's the things, I am trying to do deferred shading with multisample texture.
To create the GBuffer, I create a framebuffer with mutlisample texture attachments to draw on and a framebuffer with normal texture attachments for copying result. (Since I can't directly read multisample texture).

After lighting pass, I discoverd edges are not properly anti-aliased, see the picture below.

[image: Deferred shading result]

(you can see the jig-saw between the light and shadow)

So I look into the gbuffer content, and it appears that `Position` buffer which use `float` texture format are **NOT** anti-aliased. But `Albedo` buffer which use `unsigned byte` texture format looks good.

Here're how those buffer looks, the upper one is the `Position` buffer and the bottom one is the `Albedo` buffer

[image: Position buffer]
[image: Albedo buffer]

Can somebody explain this? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I create a framebuffer with mutlisample texture attachments to draw on and a framebuffer with normal texture attachments for copying result.

There's your problem; that's not going to actually work.

Doing a multisample resolve *before* your lighting passes makes no sense. You're effectively blending between two positions on *different objects*. That's not going to produce a meaningful result.

If you're going to do multisampling in deferred rendering, you have to use [per-sample shading](http://I%20create%20a%20framebuffer%20with%20mutlisample%20texture%20attachments%20to%20draw%20on%20and%20a%20framebuffer%20with%20normal%20texture%20attachments%20for%20copying%20result.) in the fragment shader and read each sample (with [`texelFetch` on `sampler2DMS`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)#Direct_texel_fetches)) to do your lighting passes. You would also be writing to a multisample image.

Only that last image is the one that gets the multisample resolve operation done on it.

Comment: But the last two image are both attached to the same framebuffer and I blit the framebuffers' each attachment using the same filtering method. Why only the last one gets the resolve?

Comment: Also for the position buffer, when I changed the format to ubyte, I can see the msaa working. But the value is clamped, it won't work for the shadow mapping.

Comment: @xubury: "*Why only the last one gets the resolve?*" You misunderstand. I'm explaining what you *ought to do* when doing MSAA with deferred rendering, not what you are *currently* doing. You *never* resolve your normal, position, or any of the other gbuffers. You only do a resolve on the final data computed from your lighting pass.

Comment: Ok. So what you mean is Geometry buffer can't directly have MSAA like other buffers do?   I tried 'texelFetch' but getting the same result.

Comment: @xubury: I said you can't *resolve* the buffers. Your gbuffers can be multisampled, but your lighting passes have to read all of the samples individually, do lighting on them, and then write those values to each of the samples of the final image. That is the image you do a resolve on.

Comment: Oh.Thanks! I understand it now. I get it working altough the fps drop like 5-10.